# Separable algebras and separably closed local rings (a.k.a strictly Henselian local rings)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, separable-algebras

Let $A$ be a local ring. Say a *monic* $f\in A[x]$ is unramifiable if it admits a simple root in its universal splitting algebra (equivalently, it admits a simple root in any ring over which it splits). Say a local ring is *separably closed* if every unramifiable polynomial admits a simple root. By a result of Wraith, the separably closed local rings are precisely the strictly Henselian ones.

A separably closed field is precisely one without separable extensions.

Is it also true that (injective?) separable algebras over a separably closed local ring are isomorphisms?

Comment: What do you mean by "splitting" and "simple root" over a general ring?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly "split" = is a product of degree one polynomials. "simple root" = root at which the formal derivative is *invertible*.